# Cannot get my format for date from string

Tags: mysql

I am not able to process my date format from inputs of dates like `Jan-05-1975` , Kindly let me know what is wrong with following sql query. I want the format from the input to be in `dd-mm-yyyy`

```
Select STR_TO_DATE ('Jan-05-1975','%e-%b-%Y')
OR
Select DATE_FORMAT ('Jan-05-1975','%e-%b%-Y')
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you are passing in a string initially, you should convert it to a date first, then convert to the format you want.  This uses both [`STR_TO_DATE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) and then [`DATE_FORMAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format):

```
Select Date_Format(STR_TO_DATE('Jan-05-1975','%b-%d-%Y'),'%d-%m%-%Y');
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/4940)

The `STR_TO_DATE` converts your current string in your format to a date value, then the `DATE_FORMAT` converts it to the preferred format of `dd-mm-yyyy`